# Apriori Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, apriori

I've heard about the Apriori algorithm several times before but never got the time or the opportunity to dig into it, can anyone explain to me in a simple way the workings of this algorithm? Also, a basic example would make it a lot easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I would assume you've read the wikipedia entry but you said "a basic example would make it a lot easier for me to understand". Wikipedia has just that so I'll assume you haven't read it and suggest that you do.

Read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) article.

Comment: Thank you, actually I've read the wiki page before but it had really poor content at that time now it even contains a real world example! =)

Answer (score 11):

### Apriori Algorithm

It is a candidate-generation-and-test approach for frequent pattern mining in datasets. There are two things you have to remember.

**Apriori Pruning Principle -** If any itemset is infrequent, then its superset should not be generated/tested.

**Apriori Property -** A given `(k+1)-itemset` is a candidate `(k+1)-itemset` only if everyone of its `k-itemset` subsets are frequent.

Now, here is the apriori algorithm in 4 steps.

1. Initially, scan the database/dataset once to get the frequent `1-itemset`.
2. **Generate** length `k+1` **candidate** itemsets from length `k` frequent itemsets.
3. **Test** the candidates against the database/dataset.
4. Terminate when no frequent or candidate set can be generated.

### Solved Example

Suppose there is a transaction database as follows with 4 transactions including their transaction IDs and items bought with them. Assume the minimum support - `min_sup` is `2`. The term support is the number of transactions in which a certain itemset is present/included.

**Transaction DB**

```
tid  | items
-------------
10   | A,C,D
20   | B,C,E
30   | A,B,C,E
40   | B,E
```

Now, let's create the candidate `1-itemsets` by the 1st scan of the DB. It is simply called as the set of `C_1` as follows.

```
itemset | sup
-------------
  {A}   |  2
  {B}   |  3
  {C}   |  3
  {D}   |  1
  {E}   |  3
```

If we test this with `min_sup`, we can see `{D}` does not satisfy the `min_sup` of `2`. So, it will not be included in the frequent `1-itemset`, which we simply call as the set of `L_1` as follows.

```
itemset | sup
-------------
  {A}   |  2
  {B}   |  3
  {C}   |  3
  {E}   |  3
```

Now, let's scan the DB for the 2nd time, and generate candidate `2-itemsets`, which we simply call as the set of `C_2` as follows.

```
itemset | sup
-------------
  {A,B} |  1
  {A,C} |  2
  {A,E} |  1
  {B,C} |  2
  {B,E} |  3
  {C,E} |  2
```

As you can see, `{A,B}` and `{A,E}` itemsets do not satisfy the `min_sup` of `2` and hence they will not be included in the frequent `2-itemset`, `L_2`

```
itemset | sup
-------------
  {A,C} |  2
  {B,C} |  2
  {B,E} |  3
  {C,E} |  2
```

Now let's do a 3rd scan of the DB and get candidate `3-itemsets`, `C_3` as follows.

```
itemset  | sup
-------------
 {A,B,C} |  1
 {A,B,E} |  1
 {A,C,E} |  1
 {B,C,E} |  2
```

You can see that, `{A,B,C}`, `{A,B,E}` and `{A,C,E}` does not satisfy `min_sup` of `2`. So they will not be included in frequent `3-itemset`, `L_3` as follows.

```
itemset  | sup
-------------
 {B,C,E} |  2
```

Now, finally, we can calculate the `support (supp)`, `confidence (conf)` and `lift (interestingness value)` values of the **Association/Correlation Rules** that can be generated by the itemset `{B,C,E}` as follows.

```
         Rule       | supp  |  conf   |  lift
    -------------------------------------------
     B ->  C & E    |  50%  |  66.67% |  1.33
     E ->  B & C    |  50%  |  66.67% |  1.33
     C ->  E & B    |  50%  |  66.67% |  1.77
     B & C ->  E    |  50%  |  100%   |  1.33
     E & B ->  C    |  50%  |  66.67% |  1.77
     C & E ->  B    |  50%  |  100%   |  1.33
```

Comment: This is a real answer

Comment: why isn't B -> E and E-> B included in the list of association rules?

Answer (score 6):

See [Top 10 algorithms in data mining](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/10Algorithms-08.pdf) (free access) or [The Top Ten Algorithms in Data Mining](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420089641). The latter gives a detailed description of the algorithm, together with details on how to get optimized implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The best introduction to Apriori can be downloaded from this book:

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php

you can download the chapter 6 for free which explain Apriori very clearly.

Moreover, if you want to download a Java version of Apriori and other algorithms for frequent itemset mining, you can check my website:

http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/